# How can I add custom fields in a custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Add Custom Fields to a Custom Post Type?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17117/how-to-add-custom-fields-to-a-custom-post-type)

I'm creating a custom post type for my wordpress site. But I want to remove the editor an put a field for uploading files. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of doing this... However, the easiest would be to use the [Advanced Custom Fields](http://advancedcustomfields.com/) plugin.

All you need to do is create a field group, select your custom post type, and then add and remove any fields.

Their [documentation](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/docs/getting-started/creating-a-field-group/) is also great.