# Php page with filters for custom fields

Tags: plugins

I have everal custom fields for my posts and I have created pages where I filter them by only 1 field by their value, for example

> Field name: Near   Value: City name

I have created a php template page, which I have placed inside my theme folder which has query to show all posts with specific city name.

Now I want to create a search place, which contains all the city names and suggests them to the user when he starts typing, and then he can choose the city name and one or two other custom field filters. I know how to create this, but I don't know hot to pass the filters to the custom php page template.

I want to sent the filters by either _GET or _POST, whichever is more convinient to a newly created php inside my theme folder. How do I properly send the values to that page, so that there I can access the values and create a wp query with the filters?

Answer (score 1):

I will share how I achieved to implement what I consider to be an advanced custom search using Wordpress out-of-the-box functionalities and `ACF`, without custom `PHP` scripts that are questionable.

1. **Creating a custom post type**
2. **Adding a custom field to the custom post type**
3. **Creating the search form**
4. **Outputting the search results**

**Custom Post Type:**
For the first step it is relatively easy, create your own custom post type, within your `functions.php` file or somewhere else:

Resources:
https://www.codexworld.com/wordpress-custom-post-types-without-plugin/

```
  function product_init() {
        $labels = array(
            'name' => 'Products',
            'singular_name' => 'Product',
            'add_new' => 'Add New Product',
            'add_new_item' => 'Add New Product',
            'edit_item' => 'Edit Product',
            'new_item' => 'New Product',
            'all_items' => 'All Products',
            'view_item' => 'View Product',
            'search_items' => 'Search Products',
            'not_found' =>  'No Products Found',
            'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Products found in Trash',
            'parent_item_colon' => '',
            'menu_name' => 'Products',
        );
    
        $args = array(
            'labels' => $labels,
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'capability_type' => 'post',
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'product'),
            'query_var' => true,
            'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-randomize',
            'supports' => array(
                'title',
                'editor',
                'excerpt',
                'trackbacks',
                'custom-fields',
                'comments',
                'revisions',
                'thumbnail',
                'author',
                'page-attributes'
            )
        );
        register_post_type( 'product', $args );
        register_taxonomy('product_category', 'product', array('hierarchical' => true, 'label' => 'Category', 'query_var' => true, 'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'product-category' )));
    }
    
    add_action( 'init', 'product_init' );
```

**Custom fields:**
Creating a custom field without `ACF` was more complicated than I expected, use Advanced Custom Fields plugin instead, and create a custom field applied to `'Type of Content'` > `'Product'` - or either custom post type you have. Create the fields such as: 'City', etc.

**Search form:**
Create a file called `searchform.php` within your template's folder, and it will contain a simple `<form>`:

```
<form id="searchform" method="get" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
    <input type="text" class="search-field" name="s" placeholder="Search" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="post_type[]" value="product" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Resources:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/17119/219065
https://artisansweb.net/create-custom-search-form-wordpress/

**Results:**
Within the `search.php` file, I go the following code:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'product',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array( 'key' => 'city', 'value' => 'Moscow', 'meta_compare' => 'LIKE' ),
        array( 'key' => 'city', 'value' => array('Edinburgh', 'Moscow'), 'meta_compare' => 'IN' ),
        'relation' => 'OR'
    )
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
        echo get_the_title();
    endwhile;
} else {
 echo "No posts";
}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Resources:
https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/03/advanced-wordpress-search-with-wp_query/
https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/meta_query.html
[Meta_query compare operator explanation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/70864/meta-query-compare-operator-explanation)

---

postscript. You will have to tweak and adapt a big portion of the code because it is of course not ready to handle all situations where you are going to be using the search function. And I found many elements in the code unnecessary and incomplete (check the resources for more), but it serves just as an example and I hope it helps you.